# Is there a figma plugin which allows for live updates to component attributes (eg. height) from a database?

Tags: figma, plugin

I've created a figma prototype which includes bar charts. I'm looking for a way to update the heights of the bars in real time based on data that I generate.

So far, I've been able to find plugins that sync to databases live, or that allow you to modify a component's height based on data, but not both.

Does anyone know of such a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Yes, you can use this plugin.
https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/736737028247625415

The default chart looks not so good but with data, it works.

---

[image]

---

[image]